# symfony2 form date mismatch with object from database

Tags: forms, date, symfony, view, mismatch

I have a really strange problem with dates in Symfony2 forms.

This is a website for holidays booking. On client's side everything works fine, but 
when (since a few days - no idea why!) try to edit a booking on the admin's side a get a date mismatch in the form. Seems like symfony form component doesn't map the dates in a proper way. This is what i see in the profiler:

Model Format    same as normalized format
Normalized Format
Object(DateTime) - 2015-04-05T00:00:00+0200
View Format 
04-04-2015

Do you have any idea what the reason of this can be? I've configured php in the proper way with time zones for web and cli, and this mismatch is there since a couple of days.

Screenshoot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9o4H.png

Answer (score 0):

I think that these dates are related to Russia, am I right?

You actually have `Object(DateTime) - 2015-04-05T00:00:00+0200` in representation of one library.

And `Object(DateTime) - 2015-04-04T23:00:00+0100` - in other library.

This is because Symfony uses `Intl` to convert DateTime objects to the TimeZone time. But PHP uses internal converter.

This year in Russia was time shifting that lead to all problems with time. Moscow TimeZone now have not UTC+4 but UTC+3. And some libraries were updated to fix this problem but others not.

You can fix it manually by compiling `Intl` by self with appropriate time shifting or you can use some spaghetti code to fix it in your applications.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This might be a reason, but not in my case.
There seems to be a big difference in date converting since symfony 2.6. I downgraded my version to 2.5, and will check for the differences soon. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Symfony has own implementation of data tables from `Intl` since 2.6 version. And there you can count 3 different libs for TimeZone converting: `Intl`, Symfony's implementation of `Intl`, PHP's timezone table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a very useful information! I'll keep that in mind on the update.